# VBS script to populate IE fields: difficulty working with iframes

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, vbscript, field, populate

I regularly enter data to a third party database. I'm trying to make a simple VBscript that will lift data from my own Excel spreadsheet and place it in the third party entry form on internet explorer. The process is working except when I get to an iframe on the entry form. Would really appreciate any help on this. I'm a novice.

I need the form to already be open before I launch the VBS (long story) so my script needs to look for the open page. I found a script that does this already. I've created a demo entry system, it goes like this:

**index.htm**

```
<html>
<body>

<p>First input box is on the_index.htm (main document).</p>
<input id="title" name="title-1" style="width: 220px;" title="enter title" type="text" value="">

<br /><br /><br /><br />
<iframe frameborder="0" id="input_frame" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="input_frame" src="the_iframe.htm">

</body>
</html>
```

**the_iframe.htm**

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Second input box is on the_iframe.htm (iframe called from the main document).</p>
<input id="title" name="title-1" style="width: 220px;" title="enter title" type="text" value="">
</body>
</html>
```

then my VBS is currently looking like this (sadly the the demo htms have to be hosted, so that the script can find the page (see the first line):

**inputscript.vbs**

```
surl ="http://www.website.com/index.htm"
set ie = nothing
set shapp=createobject("shell.application")
on error resume next
For Each owin In shapp.Windows
     if left(owin.document.location.href,len(surl))=surl then
        if err.number = 0 then
        set ie = owin
          end if     
    end if
err.clear
Next
on error goto 0
if ie is nothing then
    wscript.echo "Window Not Open"

else
IE.Document.All.Item("title").Value = "wheee1"
IE.Document.frames("input_frame").All.Item("title").Value = "wheee2"
end if
```

The "wheee1" deployment works fine, but the wheee2 generates 'object doesn't support this property or method: 'ie.document.frames(...).All'. If I get rid of the '.All' then the error is 'member not found'.

Can anyone tell if there's a simple fix here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get just frame window through `IE.Document.frames("input_frame")`. Since it's not a document, you need to include `Document` for this addressing too.

```
IE.Document.Frames("input_frame").Document.All("title").Value = "wheee2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is an o;d post but for anyone struggeling here is "bitty" solutions that I have used.

To get an open window -- This will only work if you are viewing with IE, firefox etc does not register with this code:

```
 For Each AW in CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
```

> 'AW = Active Windows

```
   If Typename(AW.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
```

> 'This will pick up Open Window folders and will crash withou this
>   check

```
     If InStr(1,AW.Document.Title,<String HTML Title>) > 0 Then Exit For
   End If
 Next
```

> 'AW will be the HTML wiindow your after and can be used like creating
>   an IE object,

eg.

```
Set oIe = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

As an aside the object to interface with Excel is:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

you can then just call xl. and you normal vba commands

```
xl.workbook().worksheets().cells().value etc
```

The IFrame part - the diciculty with this one is its a Window object not a document object

So you have your active window, and you want to navigate to the iframe:

```
Set iFra = AW.Document.GetElementById(<String - iframe id>)
```

or
a collection:

```
For each iFra in AW.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe")
  iFra...
Next
```

Once you have the iframe you need to use the .ContentWindow property

So From above iFra.ContentWindow

that can them be used like the AW 1 to get all the nested properties

eg

```
iFra.ContentWindow.Document.GetElementById(<String - ID>).Value = "Sorted"
```

Note when using this, if the content refreshes then you will need to re-grab your iframe object (Set IFra command above)

A useful tip when using IE developer (f12 by default in I.E.) when looking at the html activate the field you want in the iframe then refresh the HTML in developer, you should then be able to use the get element with the ifram contents.